# How to change the path of server side excel sheet generation from java code

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have written one code for downloading Excel sheet with the help of servlet and java.My code is working fine and I am getting a download pop-up at client side also.But,one excel file with same name is getting created in Apache Tomcat directory.which is also ok (because it is helpful for user if in future he wants to download that file 
from particular location) but I don't want to store that file to tomcat directory because, We cannot give access of this folder/directory to the user.So I want to know how to store particular file at particular folder location at server and also
allow download functionality at first time to user.
**I am using org.apache.poi jar of 3.9 version**

**Note: This server side storing of file behaviour is occured only for XLS file format not for XLSX file format and also I am using only filename in FileOutputStream not full path.**

Code which I am using for XLS file format:

```
HSSFSheet sheet = ExcelUtil.createWorkBook(anyexcelBean);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + excelBean.getFileName());
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    sheet.getWorkbook().write(outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```

Code for XLXS format:

```
 protected void buildDownload(HttpServletResponse response, Workbook wb, String fileName) {
    try {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().close();
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("[WB_FILE_MGR] IOException while exporting file", e);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.